# Does return value of function occupy memory when it's not stored in any variable?

Tags: java, heap-memory

```
public class testClass{

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Output is: "+retInt());
}

public static int retInt(){
    return 1;
}

}
```

Does the value of `+retInt()` in the print statement occupies space in memory? If yes then where -- in stack or in java heap?

Answer (score 0):

`int` values are not objects. They cannot be memory-managed on their own; there exist no garbage collection that could scrape leftover `int` values. Part of the overhead of using `Integer` objects is that they need the type and memory management information needed to allow for garbage collection.

In this scenario, the `int` lives on the stack. (And is managed via the stack pointer; not on its own)

Comment: Okay, what if the function returns any other types (other than integer), say another custom object. Then what'd be the answer of this question?